# WordPress ajax file upload with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple file upload ajax request towards admin-ajax.php.

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('input[data-field=file]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});

$.ajax({
    url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});

e.preventDefault();
```

Now, if I send the ajax request anywhere else than admin-ajax.php (e. g. /test.php), the data is passed normally.

The problem is, that admin-ajax.php will always return 0 because it has the following lines:

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    wp_die( '0', 400 );
```

If I try to pass the data like this (with **processData: false**):

```
data: {
    action: 'cas_contact_form',
    data: data,
},
```

admin-ajax.php still dies with a 0.

If I remove **processData: false**, I will get an **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation** error, and I won't be able even to send the data to admin-ajax.php.

So far, it seems like a catch22 problem to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well you moved the rest of the data “down one level” now, by introducing another `data` key inside the data object. But the receiving end likely expects the data fields and the `action` key on the same level. Do `data.append('action', 'cas_contact_form');` instead after you added the input fields to `data`, that should work.

Comment: Ok, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to pass the data like this (with processData: false):
>
> ```
> data: {
>     action: 'cas_contact_form',
>     data: data, }, admin-ajax.php still dies with a 0.
> ```

Well you moved the rest of the data “down one level” now, by introducing another `data` key inside the data object. But the receiving end likely expects the data fields and the action key on the same level.

But you can append this additional parameter to the FormData object the same way you already added the input fields:

```
data.append('action', 'cas_contact_form');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append